Gradle - difference in packaging resources via sourceSet vs Jar task 'into' directive
I am working on addressing some issues with our Gradle build script. Currently, incremental builds do not work, even when adding a blank line to one of our source Java files. Running the build using the --rerun-tasks flag compiles and packages the *.class files.
Since our engineers use this as a workaround for now, the compilation and Jar packaging takes ~60 seconds to complete because the processResources task is always executed. The important bits of our build.gradle are originally:
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir '../../vcj/src'
        }
        \\ Static resources
        resources {
            srcDir '../../vcj/res'
        }
    }
}

...

// Create a single Jar with all dependencies
task makeJar(type: Jar) {
    archiveBaseName = 'fooJar'
    if (enableIncludeJar.toBoolean()) {
        from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    }
    else {
        manifest {
            attributes(
                    "Manifest-Version": "1.0",
                    "Class-Path": configurations.externalLibs.collect { 'lib/' + it.getName() }.join(' ') + ' ' + configurations.externalLibsTc.collect { 'lib/tc/' + it.getName() }.join(' ')
            )
        }
    }

    with jar
}

I changed build.gradle to the following, and now compilation and Jar packaging takes ~30 seconds because the processResources task is not being executed. Hooray!!!:
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir '../../vcj/src'
        }
    }
}

...

// Create a single Jar with all dependencies
task makeJar(type: Jar) {
    archiveBaseName = 'fooJar'
    if (enableIncludeJar.toBoolean()) {
        from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    }
    else {
        manifest {
            attributes(
                    "Manifest-Version": "1.0",
                    "Class-Path": configurations.externalLibs.collect { 'lib/' + it.getName() }.join(' ') + ' ' + configurations.externalLibsTc.collect { 'lib/tc/' + it.getName() }.join(' ')
            )
        }
    }
    
    // Package static resources
    into '', {
        from '../../vcj/res'
    }

    with jar
}

Looking at the Gradle docs for ProcessResources, it states resources are copied from the target dir, potentially processing them. What exactly does potentially processing mean here? I am assuming the Jar task's into directive accomplishes the same work ProcessResources does, with the exception of potentially processing my resource files. How wrong am I?
I've tried reading all the documentation I could find and searching online, but alas I cannot find an explanation. I am also new to Gradle, and I am somewhat green as far as my engineering experience goes.

Processing a resource could mean doing things like "expanding" property references in the resource (i.e., the resource has some templating that is filled out by the task). Of course, you should be able to do that with either processResources or jar, as both task types inherit from AbstractCopyTask (which also provides functions for file renaming and content filtering).

One benefit of doing the processing in processResources, however, is that the task can be independently up-to-date. Perhaps you modify a source file, causing the output of compileJava to change. That will tell jar it needs to run again because its inputs have changed. But that may mean any resource processing will be executed as well, even if it doesn't have to be. Though if all you're doing is a straight copy then this is not much of a problem.

@Slaw since I only package static files, my change should suffice and make my engineers happier. Regarding your second comment; why would using processResources independently be beneficial if the 'jar' task can trigger an unnecessary rerun, which always occurs in my case? It may just be my lack of experience with Gradle causing my confusion.

May have been unclear, but my point was that if you configured your jar task to actually process resources, then any invalidation of the jar task's inputs would cause that processing to rerun even if there were no changes to the resources themeselves or other resource-specific inputs. Whereas processResources would be considered up-to-date and the jar task would just copy the previously processed resources.

Ah ok, that makes more sense to me know. Thanks you for the clarification.

I do find it interesting that moving the copy of ../../vcj/res to your custom jar task cuts the build time in half. You may want to look into where those extra 30 seconds are coming from in your original configuration. Perhaps you're processing other resources without appropriate filters (e.g., filesMatching("...") / filesNotMatching("..."))? Using a build scan might help, or even running with --profile.

I'm not sure what it is exactly, I'd need to check with my engineers to confirm if everything in ../../vcj/res is to be copied or if there are things we'd need to exclude. I did  run the build w/ --debug enabled but couldn't spot anything. I'll give --profile a shot, there is another issue causing incremental build to fail, even with a simple change like adding a blank line. Maybe this flag gives me an answer to that as well?

I don't have a lot of experience with them, but as I understand it, build scans are another tool to help with diagnosing problems in Gradle builds.

@Slaw I gave the build scan --scan a shot but it didn't reveal much else that I haven't seen. Using the command gradle --rerun-tasks --scan makeJar using my original vs modified gradle.build:
8 tasks executed: compileJava>processResources>classes>4 sync tasks>custom Jar task. All tasks, except for processResources, take similar times to run. processResources task details doesn't reveal much other than action execution time floating b/t 17-25 seconds. I've looked over the remaining sections, but none reveal much else. I guess I may just be stuck w/ the mystery.

@Slaw looks like my victory was shortlived; moving the resource processing caused an unforeseen issue with Eclipse for my devs. Not sure why that is the case, but what can we do.

Per @Slaw:

Processing a resource could mean doing things like "expanding" property references in the resource (i.e., the resource has some templating that is filled out by the task). Of course, you should be able to do that with either processResources or jar, as both task types inherit from AbstractCopyTask (which also provides functions for file renaming and content filtering).

